# MySQL db is using "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" when sorting by date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have a database with a bunch of records and when I load up the page with the following SQL its really slow.

```
SELECT goal.title, max(updates.date_updated) as update_sort 
FROM `goal` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `update` `updates` ON (`updates`.`goal_id`=`goal`.`goal_id`) 
WHERE (goal.private=0) 
GROUP BY updates.goal_id 
ORDER BY update_sort desc 
LIMIT 12
```

When I do an explain it says its not using any keys and that its searching every row. Also telling me its using  "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort".

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

---

It needs to be grouped by goal_id because of the MAX() in the select is returning only one row.

What i'm trying to do is return the MAX date_updated row from the `updates` table for each goal and then sort it by that column.

---

Current indices are on goal.private and update.goal_id

---

output of EXPLAIN (can't upload images so have to put it here sorry if it isnt clear:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref           rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE          goal    ref     private         private     1           const         27    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          updates ref     goal_id         goal_id     4           goal.goal_id  1
```

Comment: please post the full explain output and table structure. BTW, MySQL can't use an index for the sorting when grouping on another column (this is why you see `using filesort`).

Comment: Is there an index on `goal.private`? How may rows are selected with `private=0` and how many rows does that table have in total?

Comment: Please add additional information, such as the output from `EXPLAIN`, to your question.  It's not very readable as a comment.

Comment: Also post all the current indices on the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  u.date_updated, g.title
FROM    updates u
JOIN    goal g
ON      g.goal_id = u.goal_id
WHERE   u.id = 
        (
        SELECT  ui.id
        FROM    updates ui
        WHERE   ui.goal_id = u.goal_id
        ORDER BY
                ui.goal_id, ui.date_updated, ui.id
        LIMIT 1
        )
        AND g.private = 0
ORDER BY
        u.date_update, u.id
LIMIT 12
```

Create two indexes on `updates` for the query to work fast:

```
updates (goal_id, date_updated, id)
updates (date_updated, id)
```

Comment: still appears to be using temporary with this method

Comment: @user: please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE updates` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE goal`, as well as output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`

Comment: @user: you haven't created the two indexes on `update`. Create them if you want to get rid of the `filesort`. Also, please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE updates` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE goal`.

Comment: I did add  those indexes but it didn't remove the use temporary table bit so I removed them

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the MAX() function causes this behaviour. It needs to look at every record to decide what rows to select. What kind of grouping are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: seems to be returning a bogus count on the results when I don't group it

Comment: Not sure whats causing the bogus count but it fixes it when I group it. any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by bogus results? Is it zero? Could you add an example result set to your question?